# Performance test with jMeter and Flow JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, flow-js

I have problem with the performance tests. I need to test the upload of file with "flow js". Here is the link what is Flow js:

https://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/

We generated conteinerId successfully, but jMeter, on the next POST request, is not possible to record it or to simulate it.

Any suggestions how to measure the upload POST?

Thanks in advance!